# Split string with % as TEXT format and preserve % symbol

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to split a string by delimiter "a". I will be performing regexmatches on the first column. However, most values are being split into NUMBER formats that cannot be override. Especially I would like to preserve the percent entries as text format.

Current, only b90 is recognized as ISTEXT

```
b90a100a100 -> b90 100 100
90%a100a100 -> .9  100 100 
100a100a100 -> 100 100 100
```

Target, I would like at least column A (b90, 90%, 100) to be text.

```
b90a100a100 -> b90 100 100
90%a100a100 -> 90% 100 100 
100a100a100 -> 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REPT("(.*)?a",LEN(A1)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","")))&"(.*)?")`

[image]

- `LEN(A1)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""))` is a number of letters "a"
- `REPT("(.*)?a", times) & "(.*)?"` makes regex like `"(.*)?a(.*)?a(.*)?"`
- `REGEXEXTRACT` splits string into strings.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is using  `TRIM` or `SUBSTITUTE`, whose output is always `ISTEXT`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(A1:A3,"a")))
```

Or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A7:A9,"a")&"")
```

Comment: Thank you! I swore I got similar split working before, turns out it had TRIM. Explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Format the three cells concerned as Plain text and apply Data > Split text into columns... with `a` as Custom Separator.